# SonarQube Jenkins plugin - ClassNotFoundException: org.sonar.api.batch.TimeMachine

Tags: plugins, jenkins, sonarqube

When I run SonarQube with the Jenkins Plugin, the analisis fails.

I use the folliwing environment:

Jenkins version 1.627
SonarQube version 5.2
SonarQube plugin version 2.3 (I also tried version 2.21)

The complete log:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1:sonar (default-cli) on project parent.pom: Unable to register extension es.excentia.sonar.citymodel.CityDecorator: Lorg/sonar/api/batch/TimeMachine;: org.sonar.api.batch.TimeMachine -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1:sonar (default-cli) on project parent.pom: Unable to register extension es.excentia.sonar.citymodel.CityDecorator
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to register extension es.excentia.sonar.citymodel.CityDecorator
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:41)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstrapper.execute(RunnerBootstrapper.java:104)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:135)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to register extension es.excentia.sonar.citymodel.CityDecorator
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.addExtension(ComponentContainer.java:206)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ExtensionInstaller.doInstall(ExtensionInstaller.java:72)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ExtensionInstaller.install(ExtensionInstaller.java:52)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.addExtensions(ModuleScanContainer.java:179)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doBeforeStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:95)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:98)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:85)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:258)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:253)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:251)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:251)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:243)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:100)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:85)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeAnalysis(GlobalContainer.java:153)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:110)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:61)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:275)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedRunner.java:166)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedRunner.java:153)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstrapper.execute(RunnerBootstrapper.java:99)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/sonar/api/batch/TimeMachine;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2436)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1806)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AdaptingInjection$2.run(AdaptingInjection.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AdaptingInjection.injectionFieldAnnotated(AdaptingInjection.java:209)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AdaptingInjection.fieldAnnotatedInjectionAdapter(AdaptingInjection.java:188)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AdaptingInjection.createComponentAdapter(AdaptingInjection.java:57)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehaviorFactory.createComponentAdapter(AbstractBehaviorFactory.java:44)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.OptInCaching.createComponentAdapter(OptInCaching.java:45)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.addComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:536)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.access$300(DefaultPicoContainer.java:84)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer$AsPropertiesPicoContainer.addComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1149)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.addExtension(ComponentContainer.java:204)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonar.api.batch.TimeMachine
    at org.sonar.classloader.ParentFirstStrategy.loadClass(ParentFirstStrategy.java:39)
    at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:87)
    at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:76)
    ... 63 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The City Model plugin is not compatible with SQ 5.2. It's supposed to be flagged as "not supported" in Update Center page before doing the upgrade to SQ 5.2.

Comment: So, what's the way to currently integrate projects in Jenkins with SQ 5.2?

Comment: I don't understand your question. It does not relate to Jenkins. The City Model plugin must be simply be uninstalled.

Comment: Let me explain better. I use Jenkins to build my projects, and after each build run a SQ analysis using a Jenkins plugin, named "SonarQube Plugin", version 2.3. The SQ plugin in Jenkins have an official URL that points to http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins (a page that doesn't exists). I have no control of the plugin, so I can't uninstall the "City Model plugin". Is the SQ plugin of Jenkins under SonarSource control? If so, can you provide us with a version of the Jenkins plugin that works with SQ 5.2? Thanks